# Construction of a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact connected metric space, $x_0,x_1\in X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\epsilon>0$, then there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(0)=x_0$ and $f(1)=x_1$. For every $x\in X$, there is a $t\in [0,1]$ with $d(f(t),x)<\epsilon$ and for every $t\in [0,1]$ there is an $x\in X$ with $d(f(t),x)<\epsilon$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is arcwise connected so there is a continuous funtion of an arc whose endpoints are $x_0$ and $x_1$. After this I am not sure how to proceed. My professor asked me to prove this and has said that this can be used to prove some results for the compactification of a half-line.

Can anyone suggest me how to proceed? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "$x_0,x_1\in X$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$? Do you mean that $X$ is simply a compact connected subset of the Euclidean space?

Comment: Try first to find an $\epsilon$-net, i.e. a finite number of points $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ such that $X\subset \bigcup_i B(x_i, \epsilon) $. Then find carefully a piecewise linear path connecting all these points

Comment: @tomasz $X$ is a compact connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is compact, it is totally bounded. So such a sequence as Del mentions exists (though you might want to call the points $y_i$, since $x_0$ and $x_1$ already have a different meaning in your problem). You can add the given points $x_0$ and $x_1$ to the sequence, one at each end. This gives you a sequence $y_0, ..., y_m$ beginning at $x_0$ and ending at $x_1$ and satisfying $X \subseteq \bigcup_i B(y_i, \epsilon)$.

Now since $X$ is path-connected, for each $i$, there is a curve $\gamma_i$ in $X$ with $\gamma_i(0) = y_{i-1}$ and $\gamma_i(1) = y_i$. Piece these curves together to build $f$.